# Disable Vector smash protection using C# code to get the web content

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to take screenshot of website, but every time I compile i Get Vector smash protection enabled. Is there any way to take screenshot of website which is vector smash protection enabled? Check the code i am using to take screenshot.

```
const string url = "https://search.abc.net";

var log = Devices.Desktop;

var path = String.Format(@"C:\XYZ\search-{0}.Png", log);

Alx.Web.Screenshot.Save(url, path, ImageFormat.Png, log);
```